# Using PHP to create and save XML in subfolder

Tags: php, xml

I'm using PHP to create and save xml files using this syntax:

```
$xml->save("source1.xml") or die("Error");
```

It worked fine until i realized that i have more than 300 sources. Meaning in my folder where the working files e.g.; my css and php files i would have additional 300++ xml files mixed together with my main working files. On top of that, instead of hardcoding "source1.xml" i made it dynamic based on the selected source and create the xml file dynamically if, say, the selected source is "source189.xml" and that particular file doesn't exist.

So i added this before adding the nodes and child for xml doc:

```
$path = 'xml_'.$level.'_syll/';
$filename = $src.'.xml';
$file = $path.$filename;
```

With that, i save my xml using this:

```
$xml->save($file) or die("Error");
```

and got this error:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::save() [domdocument.save]: Unable to access xml_data_syll/source3.xml in file.php on line 85

Warning: DOMDocument::save(xml_data_syll/source3.xml) [domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file.php on line 85
Error
```

So i guessed it has something to do with permission. I googled and found a solution using chmod to grant the permission. so how do i insert the chmod during the file saving?

I tried:
$xml->save($file(chmod($file,0777))) or die("Error");

and the error i got is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function xml_data_syll/source3.xml() in file.php on line 86
```

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DOMDocument::save()` doesn't create intermediate directories if they don't exist. So you need to check the existence of the directory and create it before you call `save()`:

```
if (!is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0700);
}
```

After this you can call `$xml->save($file)`

Comment: Please take note that initially the directory was manually created. Only the xml files were dynamic. The problem was the folder permission . Not the file permissions. With the mkdir and permission granted not only can the files be created dynamically…the folder as well with the assigned permission. Thank you very much...